# Thief in a maze

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I have a problem with one excersise:

We have a thief with energy k and a maze (n x m) given with matrix of values as natural numbers. So the thief starts in the left top corner and makes his way down. His goal is obviously to steal as much as he can with his energy. For every step he uses 1 unit of energy.

He can move in two ways:

1. He can go one step right
2. He can jump to first column of next line

(So he is stealing in every line 'from the left'.)

When he runs out of energy he exits the maze (i think he can jump out of the maze in some line other than end line).

For example i understand A mouse in the maze (mouse eating as much cheese as possible) but i dont have an idea how to include energy here.

How can i write recursive equation for this question?

Is there DP solution to that (i.e. with matrix manipulation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following recursive function will output a tuple of maximum possible loot and the path to achieve it in a list of row-column tuples:

```
def steal(maze, energy, row=0, column=0):
    if energy <= 0 or row >= len(maze) or column >= len(maze[row]):
        return 0, []
    loot, path = max(
        steal(maze, energy - 1, row, column + 1),
        steal(maze, energy - 1, row + 1, 0)
    )
    return maze[row][column] + loot, [(row, column)] + path
```

For example:

```
m = [
    [2, 8, 3],
    [6, 5, 1],
    [9, 4, 7]
]
print(steal(m, 5))
```

will output:

```
(30, [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)])
```

Comment: Thank you :) I was thinking about adding two arguments for row and column but wasnt sure.

Comment: I just realized that `itemgetter(0)` is unnecessary since comparing the first item is already the behavior of tuple comparisons. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to Knapsack problem in some ways. and you can solve it by either dp or recursive.
look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/) link, it'll give you a better understanding of this problem.
your problem is a little bit different but the logic is the same.